# I want to unify the x-axis of the selected face edge vertices to the minimum value x-axis

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

**I want to unify all the duplicates created with repeat zone to the min value of the x axis**
[image]

I tried moving it using set position.
Selection could control the minimum x vector of each replicated mesh by selection.
[image]
[image]

I sent the minimum value of the x-axis of the mesh before duplication to the selected x-axis with set position, but there was no change in the x-axis.

[image]

I feel like I can manipulate it if I can access each replicated mesh with a for statement called repeat zone, but I don't know how to express it in geometry node.
Maybe give each replicated mesh an index or ID?
I'm sorry, but please tell me who

[image]

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You want, for each duplicate, to select the vertices with minimum $x$ within this duplicate (the leftmost vertices), and move them all to the "global" (common to all duplicates) minimum $x$?

Comment: yes. that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the repeat zone doesn't change what is the leftmost part, you can store the selection early on, before you pass the geo to the repeat zone. After the repeat zone you can use this selection to move all vertices of it to their current $yz$ (don't change them), but nullify (multiply by 0) the $x$ component and then use (add to 0) the minimum found in *Attribute Statistic* node:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.
It would be a good idea to set the x vector to 0 and add the minimum x-axis value.
Thank you for teaching me the techniques that made node work so neat.
As a side note, is it possible to assign an index or ID to each mesh of a repeat zone node?
As far as I can think, if you convert the mesh to an instance once, you can control it on each instance.
With mesh, it is not possible to assign idnex or id to each mesh one by one, because mesh can only assign indexes to vertices and edges.
Do you agree with this understanding?

Comment: @vectorman Let's start with... What is a *"Mesh"*? In Blender, *"Mesh"* is a type of an object and also the data of that object. Modifiers, including Geonodes, modify this data. So you have a single mesh. What it seems you mean by *"Mesh"* is the geometry you pass to the repeat zone. It seems there are no disconnected elements within one *"Mesh"* as you call it, so you can simply use the *"Mesh Island"* node to tell them apart.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.
I was able to understand it very well.
If you want to operate individual meshes, you can use the mesh island node index.
I will continue to study CG more deeply.